# Replace field with foreign key to another table in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table of phone numbers with a phone number ID as the primary key [I'll call it table 1], and another table with with a list of customers. Some of those customers have a phone number in the phone number field [table 2.] Does anyone know how I could replace the numbers in table 2 with a foreign key that points to the number in table 1?

Comment: You should show code for what you've tried and explain how it's not meeting your expectations.

Comment: What if table 2 has phone numbers that are not found in table 1?   If your data scheme is well designed, your work will go well.  Otherwise it won't.  If you want some phone numbers in table 1 and others in 2, you probably need to learn more fundamentals before trying to develop this database.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lnes:

```
UPDATE T2 
SET    T2.phonenumber = T1.PRIMARY_KEY
FROM   TABLE2 AS T2
       INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS T1 ON T1.phonenumber = T2.phonenumber
```